# I have been trying to figure this one out as well but only want to print the continents, Ex Africa, Asia, South America

Tags: python

Fill in the blanks to complete the “countries” function. This function accepts a dictionary containing a list of continents (keys) and several countries from each continent (values).

For each continent, format a string to print the names of the **countries only**.
The values for each key should appear on their own line.

```
def countries(countries_dict):
    result = ""
    # Complete the for loop to iterate through the key and value items 
    # in the dictionary.
    for continent, countries in countries_dict.items(): 
        # Use a string method to format the required string.
        result += str(countries) + '\n' 
    return result

print(countries({"Africa": ["Kenya", "Egypt", "Nigeria"], "Asia":["China", "India", "Thailand"], "South America": ["Ecuador", "Bolivia", "Brazil"]}))

# Should print:
# ['Kenya', 'Egypt', 'Nigeria']
# ['China', 'India', 'Thailand']
# ['Ecuador', 'Bolivia', 'Brazil']
```

also tried this...

```
def countries(continent_dict):
    for continent, countries_list in continent_dict.items():
     print(continent + ":")
     for country in countries_list:
       print("- " + country)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me what it is that you want, that is not being produced with your current code.

The code you have prints the list of countries, just as you have described in your comment statements "Should print".

You have made that more complicated than it needs to be. Once you have constructed your dictionary, you can achieve the same result with a simple:

```
for continent, list_of_countries in dict_of_countries.items():
    print(list_of_countries)

['Kenya', 'Egypt', 'Nigeria']
['China', 'India', 'Thailand']
['Ecuador', 'Bolivia', 'Brazil']
```

If you just want to print the continents ...

```
for continent in dict_of_countries.keys():
    print(continent)
```

This is basic iteration of keys, values in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Requirement in line-6 : Use a string method to format the required string

As per the requirement, used the format method to print the list of countries of different continents that should appear on their own line.

```
    for continents, countries in countries_dict.items():  
        result+= "{}".format(countries) + '\n'  
    return result
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?